# Netbeans desktop shortcut file not working in Unity launcher, Exec command works in term

Tags: command-line, unity, launcher, netbeans

I've been having trouble with the Netbeans desktop file generated by the netbeans install script. The file in question, as found in the /usr/share/applications folder, is very simple:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=NetBeans IDE 8.0
Comment=The Smarter Way to Code
Exec=/bin/sh "/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans"
Icon=/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/nb/netbeans.png
Categories=Application;Development;Java;IDE
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=0
```

The netbeans application itself runs perfectly fine if I run it from a terminal using `/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans`. Am I missing something here? I can't figure out how to get the error output if I run it by double-click or from the launcher. There are no errors on the terminal run. Any ideas?

**Edit:** The netbeans file is executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue by looking through syslog. I probably should have done that to begin with, but I'm still a Linux noob. Sorry if I wasted anyone's time!

Apparently, Netbeans was failing to pick up a tool agent. Specifically, the instrumentation tool Jayatanaag.jar. For some reason, this didn't cause a fail state when starting directly from a terminal, but caused fail only when running from the .desktop file. To fix this error, I uninstalled and reinstalled jayatana:

```
sudo apt-get purge jayatana
sudo apt-get install jayatana
```

This fixed the issue immediately.

Answer (score 1):

try without  `/bin/sh`

```
Exec=/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans
```

Comment: I had tried that initially. I've solved the problem now, though, so it's cool. Sorry to waste your time and thanks!

Comment: `/bin/sh` is indeed redundant, but it should not cause any problem

Answer (score 0):

First an explanation, thank you [@kos](https://askubuntu.com/users/380067/kos)

By using an `Exec=` line such as

```
Exec=/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans
```

`netbeans` is executed in `sh` already, because the `Exec=` lines in desktop files are executed as commands in `sh`, not in `bash` or else. So

```
Exec=/bin/sh -c "/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans"
```

spawns an excessive sh instance. Just

```
Exec=/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans
```

will run `netbeans` in `sh`

---

If you really need for some reasons `sh`, than your `Exec=` property is wrong.

Here is an example with Eclipse, an other Java based IDE

```
% sh "/opt/eclipse/eclipse"
/opt/eclipse/eclipse: 1: /opt/eclipse/eclipse: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

To start a command with `sh` you need the `-c` switch:

```
Exec=/bin/sh -c "/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans"
```

---

```
-c string
    If the -c option is present, then commands are read fromstring.
    If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional
    parameters, starting with $0.
```

Comment: The `Exec=` line is always run in a `sh` instance, so `/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans` will be executed in `sh` already ;)

Comment: @kos yes, I know, therefore I wrote, "If you really need..." :)

Comment: What I meant is that by using an `Exec=` line such as `Exec=/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans`, `netbeans` is executed in `sh` already, because the `Exec=` lines in desktop files are executed as commands in `sh`, not in `bash` or else. So `Exec=/bin/sh -c "/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans"` spawns an excessive `sh` instance. Just `Exec=/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans` will run `netbeans` in `sh`

Comment: @kos yes, you're right, but some installers create an Exec property like this and it's good to know, where the problem is.

Comment: @kos updated my answer

Comment: @kos and @A.B.  for info !! i installed new netbeans 8.0 it also creating by default `Exec=/bin/sh "/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans" `

Comment: Without a `-c`?

Comment: yes  and working fine !!  `[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=NetBeans IDE 8.0
Comment=The Smarter Way to Code
Exec=/bin/sh "/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans"
Icon=/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/nb/netbeans.png
Categories=Application;Development;Java;IDE
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=0`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "it's good to know, where the problem is"... Some programs probably add `/bin/sh -c [...]` or `/bin/sh [...]` because they are meant to run over Linux distributions other than Ubuntu, where the command may not run on `sh`. I think it's done "just to make sure"

Comment: @pl_rock ^^ If you change the `Exec=` line from `Exec=/bin/sh "/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans"` to `Exec=/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans` it should work anyway, at least on Ubuntu

Comment: i have change to Exec=/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans its working fine with both way also working `Exec=/bin/sh -c "/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans" `

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the desktop, create a launcher, then add: "/usr/share/applications/netbeans-8.2.desktop" as the command, and give it a meaningful title. You'll get an untrusted application warning the first time you run it; choose Mark Executable.

Happy coding.